# Handling error from server in ember

Tags: ember.js

When i try to handling the response from server, I cant able to read the error status and detail (i.e., those fields are empty)

Below i show my response what i am getting,

```
{
"message": "Ember Data Request POST http://192.168.1.21:8888/api/test returned a 0?Payload (Empty Content-Type)?",
"name": "Error",
"errors":
[
  {
  "detail": "",
  "status": "0",
  "title": "The backend responded with an error",
  }
],
"description":undefined,
"fileName":undefined
}
```

Why this fields are empty? what should i do to overcome this?

Comment: I would suggest using a REST client and debugging the server problem.  Capture your request and send it using a REST client and see what HTTP response you are getting.

Comment: can you just give your code here?

Comment: I am having a similar issue since upgrading to Ember 2.12, when I throw errors during a .save() operation all I get on the detail is "[object Object]"... I know the error was in there.